# Recording active user when using a Create view in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Basically I have a Create view where people can create database entries that looks as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Trade</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.active)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.active)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.active)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

The database also has a field called "Name" that I would like to contain the name of the user that created the entry. I am able to get the username of the current user using @User.Identity.Name but I am not sure how to make it so this is added to the Name field automatically when the user clicks "submit".

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to fill it into the name field.  In the controller that handles the post, just use:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Create(Trade trade) { 
trade.Name=HttpContext.User.Identity.Name; //this is where the current user is added
if (ModelState.IsValid) { 
db.Movies.Add(trade); 
db.SaveChanges(); 
return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
} 
return View(trade); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand, where in the controller should I put that?

Right now my controller for Create() looks like:

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /ActiveTrades/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Trade trade)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Movies.Add(trade);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(trade);
        }